# Find and replace code before div container

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext3

Trying to use Sublimetext to clean-up some code in about 900 html files.

What is the regex expression to find & replace all code **before** the 
`<div class="dngContent">` & all code **after** the `</div><!-- dngContent-->` ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfrxR.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do such thing in few steps.

- Remove all \n\r by replacing it with nothing.
- find

  - where: ^.*<div class="dngContent">(.*)</div><!-- dngContent-->.*$
  - replace: $1
- Add \n back (if needed) using auto format